# Sort torrent files into folders of 100GB based on contents

Tags: bash, knapsack-problem, bittorrent

I have a folder full torrent files that I would like to sort into a more manageable size, based on the size of contents of the torrent files.

This is the simplest way I found to have a list with the size of each torrent file's referenced contents:

```
for file in *.torrent; do 
head -1 "$file" | grep -aoE '6:lengthi[0-9]+' | cut -di -f2 | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}'; 
done
```

I have not been able to figure out a clever way to move those files into folders so that they are not more than 100GB.

I want it to end up like this:

```
directory 1
---> torrent 1 - 50GB
---> torrent 2 - 25GB
---> torrent 3 - 24GB

directory 2
---> torrent 1 - 10GB
---> torrent 2 - 85GB

directory 3
---> torrent 1 - 90GB
```

I believe that this is a "Multiple knapsack problem" - though I am only looking for an approximation. It would be interesting to learn how to solve with an optimal solution - a simpler approach is to fill a directory up until the next file would overflow and then move on to the next bucket, even if this leaves empty space.

Comment: what deeper problem are you trying to solve this way? is a greedy algorithm not sufficient to get rough partitioning?

Comment: Deeper problem? I don't want all of these in a single instance of a client. If by greedy, you mean, leaving gaps of 10GB, 15GB, etc. without solving for optimal fit, then yes, that is sufficient. My question is about the mechanics of the sorting of files based on a list in a bash script, not some perfect optimal knapsack solving algorithm.

Answer (score -1):

You either need a CLI tool that extracts the actual file sizes from the torrent or a library that handles bedecoding and possibly higher-level abstractions such as getting the list of files and then implement the splitting on top of that.

Using grep and awk is too brittle since the torrent can contain text strings match your patterns.